# mongodb complex map/reduce - or so I think

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection that contains every sale and looks like this

`{_id: '999',
buyer:{city:'Dallas','state':'Texas',...},
products: {...},
order_value:1000,
date:"2011-11-23T11:34:33Z"
}`

I need to show stats about order volumes, by state, in the last 30,60 and 90 days.
so, to get something like this

```
State          Last 30       Last 60     Last 90
Arizona        12000         22000       35000
Texas          5000          9000        16000
```

how would you do this in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

That's not very difficult :

```
map = function() {
   emit({key : this.buyer.state, value : order_value})
}

reduce = function(key,values) {
    sum = 0;
    values.forEach( function(o) {
         sum += o
         }
    return sum
   }
```

and then you map reduce your collection with query {date : {$gt : { [today minus 30 days] }}
(i d'ont remember the syntax but you should the excellent mapreduce doc on mongodb site).

To make more efficient use of map reduce, think with [incremental map reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-MongoShellScriptwithIncrementalMapReduceandFinalize) by querying first on the last 30 days, then map reduce again (incrementally) filtering -60 to -30 days to get information on the las t60 days. Finally, run incremental map reduce filtering -60 to -90 days to get the last 90 days.

This is not bad because you have 3 queryies but you only recompute aggregation on data you don't have yet.

I can provide example, but you should be able to do it by yourself now.

Comment: @CatalinM  That's more complicated but not impossible : you have to create more complicated reduce function (and use a more complicated key in map including the date value). However I recommand to execute 3 map reduce. Is there any reason to run onyl one query ?

Comment: @CatalinM if performance is why you want to do ony query : the only solution to do it in one query is very javascript-style and very slow (much more than doing 3 map reduce at least). Think also that you can do incremental map reduce, see my updated answer